# How to read from resource file outside jar

Tags: java

I want to read the configuration file outside the jar, how should I do?
I tried `classloader.getResourceAsStream("config.xml")` and succeeded while I am running the code inside Intellij. Now I want to build the jars to a folder and place the `config.xml` under the same folder, not inside the jar, but the program fails to detect the `config.xml`.

Is there a graceful way of reading the `config.xml` instead of using `File` with relative path in the code, which doesn't work while debugging/running inside the IDE?

Comment: Your code looks for a resource named config.xml in the classpath. So, if the folder containing this file is in the runtime classpath, that will work. Otherwise, it won't. As simple as that.

Comment: Instead of relying on the classpath, try reading it as a normal file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, turn it into a system property, and provide it to anything running any Java process/application.

Let's say you have a `config.xml` file located inside `/some/path/down/the/line/`, then you can do: `java --classpath ... -Dapp.config=/some/path/down/the/line/config.xml tld.domain.Application`.

Then all you have to do in your Java code is to reference that name/path: `final String configFile = System.getProperty("app.config");`, and use any well-known routine to read it from there.

Basically, you have to make sure the file/path/location is provided somehow to the Java classpath.